# Using a string as the argument to a Django filter query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to do a django query, but with the possibility of several different `WHERE` parameters.  So I was thinking of doing something like:

```
querystring = "subcat__id__in=[1,3,5]"
Listing.objects.filter(querystring)
```

Here Listing is defined in my model, and it contains the Many-To-Many field `subcat`.   However, that raises a `ValueError` because filter doesn't accept a string as its argument.  Is there a way in Python to have a string evaluated as just its contents rather than as a string?  Something like a print statement that prints the value of the string inline rather than to the standard output.

By the way, the reason I don't just do

```
querystring = [1,3,5]
Listing.objects.filter(subcat__id__in=querystring)
```

is that I'm not always filtering for `subcat__id`, sometimes it's one or several other parameters, and I'd rather not have to write out a bunch of separate queries controlled by if statements.  Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Perhaps...

```
filter_dict = {'subcat__id__in': [1,3,5]}
Listing.objects.filter(**filter_dict)
```

Comment: @danny Accepted answer then? =P

Comment: Is it possible to do or using this pattern. e.g. `Q(subcat__id__in =[1,3,5]) | Q(cat__id=9)`?

Answer (score 9):

```
Listing.objects.filter(**{"subcat__id__in": ast.literal_eval("[1,3,5]")})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do an OR query like this:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

query_as_dict = {"subcat__id__in": [1,3,5], "cat__id": 9}
query = reduce(or_, (Q(**{key: value}) for key, value in query_as_dict.items()))
Listing.objects.filter(query)
```